when i try to run my spring boot project i got this error : Error creating bean with name 'delegatingApplicationListener'
Exception in thread "task-2" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'delegatingApplicationListener': Singleton bean creation not allowed while singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:220)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:207)
at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.retrieveApplicationListeners(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:245)
at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.getApplicationListeners(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:197)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:134)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:404)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:361)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.publishEventIfRequired(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:99)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.access$100(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:50)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher$DataSourceSchemaCreatedPublisher.lambda$postProcessEntityManagerFactory$0(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:200)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
2024-04-02 17:50:51.047  INFO 1256 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2024-04-02 17:50:51.068  INFO 1256 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-04-02 17:50:51.343 ERROR 1256 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

Description:
Parameter 1 of constructor in com.furkannsahin.parking.api.BlacklistRestController required a bean of type 'com.furkannsahin.parking.mapper.BlacklistMapper' that could not be found.
Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'com.furkannsahin.parking.mapper.BlacklistMapper' in your configuration.
Process finished with exit code 0
i don't know what to do

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
